# one-word: inability to work outside a comfort space

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for *someone who can't get any productive work done outside of a particular space*?

for example: I can't get myself to work if I am at a friend's place despite having all the tools required to do work (computer, table, etc.) I can only get work done at my office or my home.

How does one summarize this idea into a single term?

Comment: There is no single word to describe/summarize both of your sentences. Perhaps you could just say - *"I am not very productive outside my comfort zone, despite the availability of work-related tools."*

Comment: Two words:  Minnesota winter.

Comment: Unproductive? Non-productive?

Answer (score 1):

"Homebody" seems like it would describe specifically not being able to work outside your comfortable *home*, although it also implies one is a bit reclusive. I'm not sure if there's a more general term, aside from adjectives regarding one's personality, like being "fastidious," "anal," or "particular" about a workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***unadaptable*** and ***adaptability-challenged***.

> unadaptable: not having the ability to change or be changed in accordance with altered circumstances.
>
> ANTONYM: adaptable - capable of adapting (of becoming or being made suitable) to a particular situation or use; *to succeed one must be adaptable*.

[FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unadaptable)

Answer (score 0):

"Agoraphobia [is an] abnormal fear of being helpless in an embarrassing or unescapable situation that is characterized especially by the avoidance of open or public places." From: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agoraphobia

While your description is of a more narrowly defined condition, it may be a lesser or weaker form of agoraphobia, especially if attempting to work in unfamiliar surroundings is accompanied by anxiety.

Comment: Unless sindhus feels anxiety or other emotions that prevent him from being productive, I'm not sure this is the best term.  I have felt similarly unproductive when working from home before.  While I wasn't anxious, nervous, or embarrassed, working from home can have too many personal distractions and does not foster my mind to be as focused on work as when I am in the office.